# Equivalent of a React container and presentational component in Vue.js

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I would like to separate the **business logic** and the **template** of a component.
In *React* I would use the *Container/Presentation* pattern.

```
const Container = (props) => <Presentational ...props/>
```

But what is the equivalent with *vue.js*?

Say I have this all in one component (did not test this one, it just for example) :

```
<template>
  <div id="app">
    <div v-for="user in users">
      {{user.name}}
    </div>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
Vue.component({
  el: '#app',
  props: {
    filter: "foo"
  }, 
  data: {
    users: [],
  },
  ready: function () {
     this.$http.get('/path/to/end-point?filter='+this.props.filter)
         .then(function (response) {
             this.users = response.data
         })
  }
})
</script>
```

How I could extract a container with just the fetch logic?

Comment: First thing would be to use `Vue.component` instead of `new Vue`, [have you read the guide?](https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/components.html)

Comment: If you are just starting the project, consider using vue2 instead of vue1.

Comment: Yes, it was just a code example. I use vue2.

Comment: As far as I know (and according to this article: https://hackernoon.com/one-major-reason-vuejs-gt-react-4edcb400e383), Dumb/Smart components pattern is very uncommon in Vue, as the template can be separed from the script with single file components (while in react Render function is still script with jsx). But Vue script-part are pure js objects, so nothing should stop you from putting them in a different file and require them if you don't want to use mixins.

Comment: haaa, this is a good catch. I will explore this.

Comment: Take a look at this article. I think it's a good example: https://markus.oberlehner.net/blog/advanced-vue-component-composition-with-container-components/

Answer (score 2):

I really don't see a *need* for a container component.  Abstract your fetch code out into a vuex action and bind your store state within the component using computed properties.

Answer (score 1):

You can extend any Vue component, which will allow you to override any methods from the parent. So, you can create a base component and then extend that:

```
const Base = Vue.component('base-comp', {
  template: "#base",
  data() {
    return {
      name: 'foo'
    }
  }
});

const Child = Base.extend({
  data() {
    return {
      name: 'bar'
    }
  }
});

Vue.component('child-comp', Child)
```

You can check out the JSFiddle here: https://jsfiddle.net/tdgxdhz9/

If you are using single file components, then it's simply a case of importing the base component and extending it, which keeps the original template in tact:

```
import Base from './BaseComponent.vue'

Base.extend({
  // Javascript code here
})
```

Comment: It is also a good catch. But I would prefer to use composition over inheritance like I use to do. But it could fit my need for the moment indeed.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [vuex-connect](https://github.com/ktsn/vuex-connect) to create container components like in React. Here an example of project : https://github.com/pocka/vue-container-component-example

Answer (score 0):

What you are looking for is Vue Mixins.
You can write a mixins file which contains your business logic and import it into your Vue components.

Link:- https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/mixins.html

Comment: Thx, but this is not exactly what I am looking for as with mixins my presentational component need to know the mixins.
I am looking for a neat separation like in React : const Smart = (props) => <Dumb ...props/>

Comment: I haven't used react yet. But have a look at global mixins.